# Is there a way to "Bookmark" answers?

Tags: support, answers, bookmarks

I have to admit I didn't really search in-depth for this feature, but is it possible to "Bookmark" or "Star" answers like in Gmail?

Comment: Same as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/is-there-any-way-to-favorite-bookmark-an-answer and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/mark-answer-as-favorite

Answer (score 19):

Everyone is pointing at the star for favorite *questions*. But the OP specifically said "Answers". It seems to me that occasionally I've tripped over an answer that itself was worth remembering, perhaps even more than the question itself.

This most often happens on those large survey/fun questions where an interesting answer might be buried on page 3...

Perhaps there should be a small start next to the `link | flag` set of actions....

Perhaps this answer should itself become a feature-request question...

Answer (score -2):

Click on the Star next to a question to mark it as a favorite.

Select Users, click the "Activity" tab, then select the sub-tab "favorites" to see all the questions you have starred.

In the future, there is a website specifically for questions about SO, [Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Making a question a favorite will not mark a particular answer. In most cases where there are only a few it will be enough, but in some cases that has a lot of answers and you don't want to save the high ranking one, this will not help. But it should be enough in most cases.

Comment: Thanks I'm new to this. Will remember that in the future. I can't mark this as answered any more :(

Answer (score -2):

Use **Google toolbar** and use SO while logged into your google account.

You can then press the BlueStar to bookmark your pages on SO. Later wherever you install your google toolbar and log-in, **you will retain all your bookmarks wherever you go**.