# Are declined feature requests ever reconsidered?

Tags: discussion, feedback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we re-request features that were declined a sufficient while ago?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89026/can-we-re-request-features-that-were-declined-a-sufficient-while-ago)

There are [quite a few](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-declined?sort=votes) feature requests that were declined in spite of being (or becoming) very popular.

Are these ever reconsidered (eg: because of new trends, shifting needs, etc.) or are they as good as dead?

Comment: I've suggested at least one thing that was [status-declined] but then ended up [status-completed] later on...