# How do we re-open feature discussions after some length of time?

Tags: discussion, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have the ability to rescind a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)
>   [Can we re-request features that were declined a sufficient while ago?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89026/can-we-re-request-features-that-were-declined-a-sufficient-while-ago)

I was researching a specific feature (rescinding close votes, seen here: [Can we have the ability to retract a close vote before it closes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes)) and it leads to a more broad discussion that I think is meta-specific: how do we discuss items that have old discussion but perhaps warrant a reconsideration?

It's been almost 3 years since this was first proposed.  Is there a process for revisiting old decisions in general?  My concern is trying to re-open discussion on old issues will just get blanket-closed as duplicates.

This is not like most of our questions on various sites: these don't have a "right" or "wrong" answer other than when someone with enough clout says "we're doing this" or "we're not doing this".  But there needs to be a way to go back and reconsider the latter category within our question workflow.

Comment: [How do I get attention for my old, unanswered questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046)

Comment: This is neither my old question, nor unanswered.  It was answered and declined.  My question is: how do we revisit what is essentially an executive decision -- how do we re-propose ideas after a suitable amount of time?

Comment: Yeah, that one's actually mistitled. It should be "How do I get attention for an old, unanswered question?" The point is you don't need to re-propose them, they've already been proposed once and there's nothing wrong with the original proposal.

Comment: You might want to consider splitting these two questions into separate posts to make it easier for everyone to respond.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: In the general case, sure.  But on meta, where feature requests have a terminal status, I don't think it quite works.  People see "feature-declined" and that's that, no matter how long ago it happened.

Comment: I disagree. Perhaps people see it that way, but that's not how I see it. Feature requests can be revisited, even if they were once declined. The existing system (posting a well-argued answer in support of the feature, placing a bounty, etc.) seems to work just fine.