# I have a suggestion that has been made before. How can I propose it?

Tags: support, meta

This suggestion is regarding the down-voting issue.  I posted an answer about it [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/allow-users-to-leave-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting/180569#180569), but I'm not sure if it'll be seen unless someone tries to ask a question and stumbles upon it.

In general, how can one suggest a change, especially one that has been asked before, and have it seen by "the right" people?

Comment: If your change significantly differs from and/or presents a newer/more relevant viewpoint, do feel free to ask another question. You need to make an argument, through your points and understanding of the issue, that your question does indeed differ from the older one, though.

Comment: You ask a question on Meta with the feature request tag and outline your proposal and its benefits. If it has already been proposed before, you can bump the question by editing meaningfully, adding an answer, or attaching a bounty (reiterating the request in a different question is wrong). There is no special way to ensure it will be seen by the "right people", which is a term I am somewhat unclear on.

Comment: These tags confuse me. `meta` is about this meta site, but the feature request is for the entire stack exchange system.  And I'm not sure why `feature-request-tag` was added to this question.

Comment: @Asad, how is it bumped?  When I added an answer, I didn't see it on the questions page.

Comment: @Adrian The question is on the front page at the moment. It was 2 hours ago though, so it has moved down the page considerably.

Answer (score 1):

> especially one that has been asked before

...you don't.  It'll be closed as duplicate.

Here is a thread discussing doing that:  [How do we re-open feature discussions after some length of time?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133111/how-do-we-re-open-feature-discussions-after-some-length-of-time)

But in general, you make a meta-post, and tag it as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).  Browse those questions for many examples.  Note downvotes mean something different on meta - usually that someone disagrees with you, not that your proposal was ill-researched or otherwise low-quality.

Comment: That's not necessarily true. There's a right way on Meta to open a discussion about a topic which has been discussed before.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi yes, I dug up the meta threads discussing doing that with feature request.