# Change hovertext for meta votes

Tags: feature-request, voting, meta

Meta votes are different; they often refer to agreement or disagreement. However, the hovertext still says stuff about research and clarity. This can be confusing to new Meta users.

We can base it on the main tags; Feature-Request, Bug, and Discussion would be something more like

> You agree with what this post has to say; it would be a good addition to the site.

Support questions would stay the same, I  suppose.

<sub>(Posted originally [on Worldbuilding Meta](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9608/change-hovertext-for-meta-votes/9626#9626) and moved here.)</sub>

Comment: Related, since the duped request was declined 11 years ago by old management: [Can we re-request features that were declined a sufficient while ago?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89026)