# How to bookmark a question in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to favorite / bookmark an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/is-there-any-way-to-favorite-bookmark-an-answer)

Is there a way to bookmark a question/answer I like in Stack Overflow, so that I can reference it later?

Comment: With your browser? There's also the star icon below the upvote/downvote arrows, which, if you hover over it, says "favorite." Ask questions like this on Meta, not here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can click on the little star under the voting numbers to **make it a favorite**. That puts it in your list of favorites, which may behave the way you want. It also credits the question with being a favorite.

Comment: What's the point using bookmark? I was going to use it on a Question without answers, because I want a notification when an answer is added.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the star to make a question your favourite. Then, look for that question in favourite tab on your home page.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the star below the question rank to add a question into your favorites.