# Why can't we star answers?

Tags: feature-request

I love when I can star some really nice questions, but sometimes the answers are incredibly detailed, and they deserve a star. When I star a question, I think of it as I like how the question was done, not the answers below it. This is an exact duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/is-there-any-way-to-favorite-bookmark-an-answer/1571#1571), but the feature was never requested, just asked if it was possible. This is a feature request.

Comment: I don't think I've ever starred a question just because I liked how it was phrased. It's always been about the answers for me. (Or a reminder to post an answer, but that's a different use case altogether.)

Comment: @Anna Some questions are very detailed, and I like that. It's not for reference, it's just that it's a very well put together question.

Comment: I'm not voting to close this as duplicate until that feature request -> general explanation of how things work chain is broken.

Comment: @djechlin I undid that final "duplicate of How do Favourite Questions Work" closure.

Comment: @IanCarroll I should rephrase then. I don't think I've ever used stars as favourites without any intention to go back and refer to the question later. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear I changed the last one to a feature request tag from support.  I think this was appropriate even though that OP was happy with the semi-solution provided, but "the spirit of it" is a feature request.

Comment: @AnnaLear note I'm not positive about that decision.  It's slightly messy getting these consolidated given the slightly different takes.

Answer (score 5):

What's the benefit?  If you like an answer just star the question.  Then you can refer to it just as easily.

Comment: Did you read the question in full? `When I star a question, I think of it as I like how the question was done, not the answers below it.`

Comment: `"Then you can refer to it just as easily."` [definitely](http://askubuntu.com/q/29553/44179) */sarcasm*

Comment: @IanCarroll then think of it differently.

Comment: @Seth I guess there's a minority of times that the most interesting answer to a user is way buried in there.  Point taken.  I still don't think this is worth a new feature.