# Option to flag/tag/bookmark a certain question/answer so that any edits/answers/comments show up in my Global Inbox

Tags: feature-request, comments, global-inbox, favorites-notifications, bookmarks

***Note:*** This is not a duplicate of [Is there any way to favorite/bookmark an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1569/is-there-any-way-to-favorite-bookmark-an-answer), since I am asking specifically about receiving notifications, nor is it a duplicate of [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox), since I am asking about a separate facility to tag individual questions.

---

I'm asking this from the context of Puzzling.SE, although I'm sure it could be relevant for all SE sites.

Often, on Puzzling, a difficult puzzle will be posted.  I will look at it, and think, "That's really interesting; I'm curious to know what the solution is."  Sometimes I will favourite/bookmark it, and continue to go back to it to see if anyone has posted an answer/comment.

What would be much more helpful to me, is if I could click something that would add that question to my SE notifications, so I get notified when someone posts an answer or comments, in the same way I get notified for my own questions.  Since people use the "favourite" functionality for different things (as a temporary bookmark, or as a way to keep a list of best questions, or as a way to give kudos for an excellent question), it doesn't seem like it should be used for this.  Rather there should be a separate "flag" of some sort that can be applied.

Once I lose interest, I could uncheck it, and I would no longer get the notifications for that question.

On Puzzling there are also often puzzles that are worked on in a "group" format:  There are many bits to the puzzle, and different people offer solutions for each bit.  Thus it would also be beneficial to receive notifications of edits on answers I have tagged/flagged/marked.  I realize this aspect might be more difficult, since it doesn't mimic the notifications supplied for my own questions, but even if the notifications of answers/comments could be implemented, it would be very helpful.

Comment: If you're still interested in this, I've made a browser extension that lets you 'watch' posts for different things (like new answers, closures, comments, etc.): [Stack Exchange Post Watcher - Firefox & Chrome extension to watch posts for any changes](https://stackapps.com/q/8278) which might be useful for you :)

Comment: Reminds me of my old post https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286057/6309

Answer (score 1):

Implementing what you're asking for might be achievable by introducing something what I'd call introducing the concept of "***labels***" to be used by a user for the purpose of personalization. Read on for more details.

#### The concept of a label

Think of a label as similar to favorites, whereas each user is free to "mark" something with such label, but with many more extra facilities, and not only to allow a user to mark selected questions using a boolean variable that is on or off (as  is the case with using favorites today).

#### Adding labels

It should be possible to use these label for basically anything that a user might want to use a label for. Here are some examples (incomplete list):

- Questions.
- Answers.
- Comments.
- Tags.
- Users.
- Reviews.
- ... (What else?).

#### Personalization of label

It should be possible for a user to define custom values (e.g using multi-value selection lists) for each of those labels, probably stored somehow in conjunction with the user's profile, and ideally with some type of indication if these labels/values are to be considered as private (not shown to anybody else) or public (visible to anybody).

Examples of such custom attributes could be:

- **Status** (= Action, WaitFor, Defer, ...), to make it possible to start processing questions (or answers, comments, etc) in a way similar to processing your eMail inbox messages.
- **Context** (= Question, Answer, Comment, User, ...), to configure for which kind of SE objects you want to be able to use a specific label.
- **Mark as** (= Read, Unread), similar to how eMail clients allow marking messages as read or unread.
- **Follow** (= Boolean which is off be default), to get notified about events about a post (like new answers to a question, edits of a post, new comments to a post, etc).
- **Vote** (=ToDoUp, ToDoDown, ToRevisit, ToUndo), to keep track of voting actions about posts that you want to perform later on).
- **Like** (= Boolean which is off be default, similar to current favorites).
- **Ignore** (= Boolean which is off be default, similar to how you can ignore specific tags).
- **Note** (some kind of free form text), to optionally add some special note to remember later on why you added some label to a question, answer, user, etc.
- ... (What else?).

#### Examples to use such labels

To address your feature request, only the personalization feature **Follow** (as explained above) needs to be implemented (for questions). But here are some more examples how such labels could be used:

- Write an answer to this **question** (for which I need to do some research first).
- Add this interesting ***answer*** to my reading list.
- Wait for feedback from OPer of a **question** (to which I submitted an answer before).
- Remember to reply to some specific **comment**.
- Visit other answers from some **user** who seems to be an expert on topic X.
- Remember to **vote** on some post later on (today I ran out of votes ...).
- Annotate some post to perform some **voting action later on** (eg to revisit a post you downvoted, as an alternative to [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1751/286501)).
- Mark this question to possibly ever start a **bounty** for it.
- Submit an edit suggestion for this **tag**.
- ... (I could add another few dozens of such examples).

#### Implementation

Obvious, implementing the above concept is not a simple thing. But it could be like implementing a **new** concept, which can be done using a step by step approach. E.g. start with (only) answers, then comments, then tags, or users, and in the end possibly even replacing (migrating?) existing concepts like favorites (of questions).